# m-Reachability in graphs

Tags: algorithm, graph

Suppose you have an NxN maze with a Knight, Princess and Exit.

[image]

There is also an evil Witch that is planning to block `M` squares (set them on fire). She will set all these blocks on fire before the Knight makes his first move (they **do not** alternate turns).

Given the map to the maze, and M, can you decide in O(N^2) whether the Knight will be able to reach the princess, and then the exit, for any choice of blocks by the Witch (meaning - can the Witch make choices that would prevent the Knight & Princess from escaping)?

Comment: @Dan - The witch hasn't revealed which squares are going to be blocked off yet. `M` is simply an integer.

Comment: I don't get it, for M>=8 (for example) how is that possible? Maybe the witch totally surrounded the knight, maybe not. It's undeterminable if all you're given is the integer M.

Comment: @davin - I guess you could consider M a constant, because if M >= 8 the witch "wins". So any solution that would be O(n^2 * f(M)), where f() is an arbitrary function, will be legitimate.

Comment: Even if you consider M a constant and it gives the same upper bound, what I mean is that for all M>=8 (assuming knight, princess and exit are pairwise non-adjacent) there exists a scenario in which the witch can block the knight/princess/exit, so I'm not sure what you're looking for.

Comment: @davin - a solution for M < 8 :)

Comment: 8 was just an example, there are many more conditions you need to consider that can result in an easy blocking scenario, for example, if any of the three (knight,princess,exit) are touching the graph edge, then the same holds for M>=3, and come to think of it, even if the three are internal (i.e. not on the graph edge), you only need M=4 to block them... if one of them is on two edges (i.e. in a corner), then M=2 is enough... but even if you assume they're all internal, for all M>=4 the witch may or may not totally block them, and for all M<4 it's impossible to block them.

Comment: @davin - I don't understand what you don't understand. Isn't the problem as I stated well defined? The requirement is to find an algorithm that decides whether they can escape the maze, that will take O(n^2) time. I don't know how such an algorithm would be constructed, this is why I asked the question.

Comment: As was suggested, bfs or dfs should work, although even a shortest path algorithm like dijkstra should work, all in O(n^2), but you imposed a constraint that M is merely an integer, but the specific M nodes are unknown. So either the M nodes are known, in which case the algorithms mentioned should work, or M is just an integer, in which case the problem is not deterministic (for M>=4 etc.)

Comment: @davin - why do you say the problem is not deterministic? This is a perfect information problem, the state of the board and M is known. You should decide if there is _any_ set of moves the witch can play that will block the knight.

Comment: After your final edit, it has indeed become a well defined problem. Until now it was not clear that the algorithm is looking for the witch's moves.

Comment: My gut feeling is that this is not possible in O(N^2). Even without the witch, the best I can come up with is a Dijkstra path search, which would take O(N^2 log N^2) = O(N^2 log N) time, if I'm not mistaken. The N^2 limitation means that we can effectively only inspect each square a constant number of times.

Comment: Which of these is the question: "For a given set of parameters, can the witch block the knight?" or is it "For a given set of parameters, can it be decided in O(N^2)".

Comment: @Thomas - with N = 0, you can just BFS it. It may just be impossible, I don't know - it was given as an exam question.

Comment: Oh, right. We don't need the _shortest_ path. That's what you get if you hang around on SO before coffee.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem seems to be equivalent to determining if there exists `M + 1` distinct paths from the knight to the princess, and `M + 1` distinct paths from the princess to the exit. If there are only `M` distinct paths from the knight to the princess (or princess to exit), the witch can just burn one square from each path, blocking the rescue (and, alas, any chance of a happily-ever-after romance between them).

For example, the maze in your question has two distinct paths from the knight to the princess, and two distinct paths from the princess to the exit. Thus, the which can burn `min(2, 2)` to prevent escape.

The number of distinct paths between two points can be found by using a [maximal network flow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem) algorithm. Each cell in the grid is a node in the network; two nodes have an edge (of capacity 1) connecting them if they are adjacent and both white. The maximal network flow from the one point to another represents the number of distinct paths between them.

The [Ford Fulkerson algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford%E2%80%93Fulkerson_algorithm) will solve the network flow problem in `O(E * f)` time, where `E` is the number of edges in the network (at most `N^2`) and `f` is the value of the maximum network flow. Because the maximum network flow is at most 4 (the knight only has four possible directions for his first move), the total complexity becomes `O(2 * E * 4) = O(N^2)`, as requested.

**Avoiding using a node more than once**

As others have pointed out, the above solution prevents *edges* going into and out of nodes being used more than once; not the nodes themselves.

We can modify the flow graph to avoid *nodes* being used more than once by giving each cell four input edges, a single guard edge, and four output edges (each having a weight of 1) as follows:

[image: Picture of cell graph structure]

The output edge of one cell corresponds to the input of another. Each cell can now only be used for one path, as the guard edge can only have a flow of 1. Sink and source cells remain unchanged. We still have a constant number of edges per cell, leaving the complexity of the algorithm unchanged.

Comment: @davidg- I was thinking about an approach like this, and while I like the general idea, I'm not sure that flow construction works.  In particular, what happens if two units of flow enter a node and then leave it?  Wouldn't that allow for there to be two paths that each use the same node?  I think you can fix this by slightly modifying the construction by splitting each node in two, then adding a unit capacity edge between the two.  Is this unnecessary?  Or is my previous concern valid?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the maximum network flow finds edge-disjoint paths, but I think we're looking for vertex-disjoint paths. That's not a problem at all, since you can also enforce a capacity of 1 on the vertices by a simple transformation of the graph.

Comment: @templatetypedef: Quite correct. My bad. @kunigami: I have tried to given an example of such a transformation.